# Android: Change background colour of specific activity using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, radio-group

I am trying to change the background colour of a activity where the user can change the colour using 3 radio buttons in an android app. I am doing this using sharedPreferences.

So I have the activity page where the colour is chosen with the radio group and the code to use sharedPrefernces looks like this (i know the switch statement works aswell as I have a toast message apperring when the colour is supposed to change):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preferences);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("bgColour", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            String colourSelected = "";
            switch (checkedId) {
                case R.id.radioButton1 : 
                  colourSelected = "YELLOW";
                  editor.putString("colour", colourSelected);
                  editor.commit();
                  break;
                case R.id.radioButton2 : 
                  colourSelected = "YELLOW";
                  editor.putString("colour", colourSelected);
                  editor.commit();
                  break;

                case R.id.radioButton3 : 
                  colourSelected = "BLUE";
                  editor.putString("colour", colourSelected);
                  editor.commit();
                  break;
            }   
        }
    });
}
```

The XML looks like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.practical3_10327751_donnacha_holmes.Preferences" >

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Green" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yellow" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blue" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back" />
```

Then there is the activity that changes the background colour, which looks like this when trying to change the colour:

```
public class Activity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

RelativeLayout rl;
String colour;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("bgColour", MODE_PRIVATE);
    colour = prefs.getString("Colour", "WHITE");

    rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
    if(colour=="GREEN"){
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(colour=="YELLOW"){
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    else if(colour=="BLUE"){
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else{
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

I know that the background colour is being changed because it is being set to red every time I go to this page.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` operator checks to see if the two strings are exactly the same object.

The `.equals()` method will check if the two strings have the same value.

Therefore to compare Strings use `.equals()`,i.e. rewrite your comparison as

```
 if(colour.equals("GREEN")){
    rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
    else if(colour.equals("YELLOW")){
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
    else if(colour.equals("BLUE")){
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else{
        rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

and you are saving value as **colour** and try to retrieving as **Colour**,so change

```
 colour = prefs.getString("Colour", "WHITE");
```

to

```
 colour = prefs.getString("colour", "WHITE");
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I get what you mean but it did not work.. do you think it could be how I am storing the colour in sharedpreferences?

Comment: @Donnacha did you clear your project after above changes,please clear your project and retry.

Comment: @Donnacha Happy to help,enjoy.